# Authorizing YouTube API to chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube-api

I try to connect youtube API to use it in "browser_action" popup. There is a quickstart guide in  [youtube API page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript). There is a HTML code which can be copy-paste to try if it work and use it later.

Problem happens with it comes to using external .js file(youtube API) It gives me error:

```
Refused to load the script 'https://apis.google.com/js/api.js' because it 
violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 
blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:".
```

and its okay, [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy) we can learn why it works like that. Later in this article it says best way it to include the files into the project. In this case its rather hard, becouse the api.js has more links inside, and this one file doesnt do the job.

Later on in the [article](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy) its written we can add some origins to whitelist, so it would be able to load it form external source. I thing this should solve the problem, so I've added it to the manifest.

```
 "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com/js/api.js; object-src 'self'",
```

( tried also other versions like "https://apis.google.com/*" etc., but it doesn't make any difference, still getting same error.

What's the problem there? Whitelisting apis.google.com would do the job or it's bad approach? And how to do this properly.

I add full manifest, maybe there is an error

```
  {
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "YT Gniewos tryhards",
    "description": "This extension was made to learn and to try some things with youtube.",
    "version": "1.0",

    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com/*; object-src 'self'",
    "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "default_popup": "qucikstart.html",
      "default_title": "Click here!"
    },
    "permissions": [
      "activeTab",
      "storage"
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Create OAuth 2.0 credentials](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application#Create_OAuth2_Tokens) for Chrome.

> You need to specify the `Application ID` for your Chrome app or extension. Use the [Google Chrome Identity API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity) to obtain that ID.